# SecTrustCreateWithCertificates EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, crash-reports, crashlytics

I'm getting this crash log from Fabric but am unable to understand what causes it. Can anyone help to explain what cause this crash?

Here is the log from Fabric:

```
Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x000000008efcaa00

Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1808bdb90 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1811be0a4 __CFArrayCreateCopy0 + 628
2  Security                       0x181685aa4 SecTrustCreateWithCertificates + 96
3  Security                       0x18165974c sslCreateSecTrust + 204
4  Security                       0x181659c5c tls_verify_peer_cert + 80
5  libsystem_coretls.dylib        0x180d8603c SSLProcessHandshakeRecordInner + 176
6  libsystem_coretls.dylib        0x180d8a490 tls_handshake_process + 148
7  Security                       0x18165dd60 SSLHandshakeProceed + 140
8  Security                       0x18165e188 SSLHandshake + 140
9  CFNetwork                      0x1818299b8 SocketStream::_PerformSecurityHandshake_NoLock() + 464
10 CFNetwork                      0x18180440c SocketStream::socketCallback(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*) + 204
11 CFNetwork                      0x1818042fc SocketStream::_SocketCallBack_stream(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*, void*) + 88
12 CoreFoundation                 0x181201750 __CFSocketPerformV0 + 1096
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1811fd09c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1811fcab0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 412
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1811fa830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
16 CoreFoundation                 0x181124c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
17 CFNetwork                      0x1818a5c68 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
18 Foundation                     0x181c1be4c __NSThread__start__ + 1000
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180eabb28 _pthread_body + 156
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180eaba8c _pthread_body + 154
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180ea9028 thread_start + 4
```

As far as i know, in my app, I didn't do any call using SecTrustCreateWithCertificates. But I did use AFNewtworking.

Any help and explanation would be helpful.